# can server document root be relied upon

Tags: php

I wrote the PHP code for my website almost 9 years ago. I have a config file called `common.php`. Each page in my site requires this page to access the site's constants, classes and variables.

I develop on a local machine and then upload files to a live site. The code I have used on my pages to call `common.php` is:

```
$main = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost')? "E:\-=Web=-\-=Sites=-\mysite\main\common.php" :"/home/mysite/public_html/main/common.php";
require_once($main);
```

This has worked fine and has never given me any issues.

However, I figure I could instead just use:

```
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/main/common.php")
```

This would make my code more compact and it also means I do not have to have my development site files always in `E://`

So my question is, is it good practice to use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`?

Is this what most developers would do if wishing to call the config file on each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common and reliable way is to define a constant that contains the path to your code either in your index.php file, or a config.php file which is included from the same directory or a known relative path and reference that:

```
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) define('APP_DIR', __DIR__); // set the app directory to that of the currently executing file
```

Your require line for other files then becomes this

```
require_once(APP_DIR . '/main/common.php');
```

Now, you can guarantee that this constant will contain what you expect it to. Assuming you've set it right, that is. ;)

Comment: Ok thank you sir. It seems 2 lines is still better than one, although the code you wrote is more compact than what I have been using.

Comment: Sorry I am late in reporting back. I understand what this code will do. However, I do not know how to get the config.php file automatically called so APP_DIR can be accessed from any page I wish to use it on. I tried setting auto_prepend in a .htaccess file to load config.php. This worked fine on my development server but not on my hosts live server (I figure I am blocked from changing this).